# Яндекс-карта: убрать кнопку "как добраться"

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Создаю на странице карту с помощью API 2.1, нужно убрать всё, кроме зума. С помощью `.controls.remove(controlName)` получилось убрать кнопки слоев, местоположения и прочее, кроме кнопки "как добраться". Ее вообще можно как-то скрыть?

Код:

```
ymaps.ready(function () {
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map(
        'contacts-map-container',
        { center: [55.754283, 37.621053], zoom: 14 },
        { searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search' }
    );
    myMap.controls.remove('routeEditor');
    // и остальные контролы туда же
});
```

**UPD** `document.querySelectorAll('[class$="gotoymaps"]')[0].style.display = 'none';` помогает, но это немного костыльно.

Comment: Зачем вы хотите скрывать "Открывать в Я.Картах"? Пользователи обычно пользуются этой возможностью, чтобы узнать как добраться до организации предложенной на сайте или лучше понять где она расположена.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Здесь показано как добавлять только нужные контролы https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/customSet_controls .

Если нужно скрыть "Открыть в Яндекс картах", то можно воспользоваться опцией suppressMapOpenBlock https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/Map-docpage/#Map__param-options . В итоге будет так:

```
var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
        center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
        zoom: 9,
        controls: []
    }, {
        suppressMapOpenBlock: true
    });
```

Comment: Да, оно. Оказывается, в случае, если на карту добавлен маркер (как у меня там дальше происходит) кнопка "открыть в Яндекс картах" преобразовывается в "Как добраться" (а именно это я пытался найти в документации).